# Add Same fields and methods to EmbededDocument and Document class in mongoengine

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, mongoengine

I want to add timestamp related fields to both EmbededDocument class inherited documents and to regular Document class inherited Documents.

Since EmbededDocument and Document classes cannot be mixed in mongoengine I had to create a base class and tried to use that through multi-inheritance.

This is what I have done

```
class SikkaBase():
    # Passing a callable as default
    created_on = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    is_deleted = BooleanField(default=False)

    # Update the updated_on field for every update
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.updated_on = datetime.now()

        super(SikkaBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # Update the created_on field for every updates
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.updated_on = datetime.now()

        super(SikkaBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class SikkaBaseDocument(Document, SikkaBase):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }

class SikkaEmbededBaseDocument(EmbeddedDocument, SikkaBase):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }
```

This throws an error

```
 File ".../sikka_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/metaclasses.py", line 305, in __new__
    if b.__class__ == TopLevelDocumentMetaclass]
AttributeError: class SikkaBase has no attribute '__class__'
```

I am not so sure about my solution either as SikkaBase class is not related to MongoEngine in any way, not sure how relevant that is.

Looking for any possible solutions. I can always copy the same code in the SikkaBaseDocument and SikkaEmbededBaseDocument class but want to avoid doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like old-style classes do not have `__class__` attribute, therefore you should inherit from `object`. Changing your first line from

```
class SikkaBase():
```

to

```
class SikkaBase(object):
```

should fix this issue.